# How to get the difference between 2 prefetch datasets from Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

Hi everybody I have 2 datasets structured as such (with batch size 55) and Dataset 2 has all 10127 points of data, dataset 1 has 8102 points. They are structured as Tensorflow prefetch datasets as

Dataset 1:
[
(first batch of 55),
(second batch of 55),
...
(last batch ends up being of size 17)
],
Dataset 2:
[
(first batch of 55),
(second batch of 55),
...
(last batch ends up being of size 7)
]
My question was how could I get all the individual examples within the batches of 55 such that I get the points which in dataset 2 but not in dataset 1? Thanks. The resulting output should give me the 2025 examples which are in dataset 2 and not in dataset 1.

I have tried trying to get all the one values into 1 array, and getting the difference that way
but it is taking too long

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.